# Usage of Googmonify AdSense plugin for WordPress

Tags: wordpress, adsense

I want to put AdSense on top of my WP site and after each page and post title. After some research I have tried Googmonify, by considering the best for my needs and still not sure that it is. Anyway, in order to put Ads on top of my site I have tries to add

```
[googmonify]slot:align:width:height[/googmonify]
```

in index.php of the template after

```
<?php
get_header(); ?>
```

and also tried in header.php in body tag, but it does not show the AdSense instead the same code figures in the place I put it. Whereas if I put it in the html code of the post, it works perfectly. Why? How to fix the problem. Is this the best plugin for my need at all??? :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use "Include", i have used it many times and work for me perfectly.